# xcode wont allow me to upload app to my phone

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am have been programming with swift for the past week now and I have had no problems uploading my apps to my phone until now.

When I run the project I receive these 2 errors:

1. Communication with Apple failed: Your maximum App ID limit has been reached. You may create up to 10 App IDs every 7 days.
2. No profiles for [project name] were found: Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching [project name].

How do I get rid of these errors?

Comment: Either you are used Apple Developer Account which has registered two many application.

Go To Developer Account -> Remove unused App from there and Make Automatic Signed in your Xcode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have a paid Apple developer account, you have a limit for the number of new apps you can create that you can run on an actual device. You can either one, wait for a week, and manage with the Xcode simulators for now. Or two, pay for an apple developer account. Your second problem will be solved along with the first one. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is delete your app from your physical device and run it again. As soon as the app is downloaded in your physical device it will only work for a week.